# I am not able to insert facebook account to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, passport-facebook

I am trying to sign up my users using facebook using passportjs. I am using mongodb as database and using mongoose to interact with it.

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
email: String,
password: String,
googleId: String,
facebookId: String,
secret: [String],
});

const User = mongoose.model("users", userSchema);
```

This is the schema.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.APP_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.CALLBACK_URL,
    profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'email']
},
function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    //check user table for anyone with a facebook ID of profile.id
    console.log(profile);
    User.findOne({
        facebookId: profile.id
    }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        //No user was found... so create a new user with values from Facebook (all the profile. stuff)
        if (!user) {
            user = new User({
                name: profile.displayName,
                email: profile.emails[0].value,
                username: profile.username,
                provider: 'facebook',
                User.findOne({'facebook.id': profile.id } will match because of this next line
                facebook: profile._json
            });
            user.save(function (err) {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                return done(err, user);
            });
        } else {
            //found user. Return
            return done(err, user);
        }
    });
}
 ));
```

This is the code of facebook strategy. I can sign up succesfully using facebook but I am not able to add the user to my database. I have the same code for my google oauth and it seems to work in google.